# Make Chart AxisX Labels Display Days Starting from Monday

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, dayofweek

In C# charts, when defining:

```
chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "ddd";
```

The AxisX labels always start from Sunday, regardless of `FirstDayOfWeek` defined in `CultureInfo`.

Is there a way to make it start from Monday?

Comment: ?? The labelling follows the data. How are you adding data and what are they?

Comment: My data is a set of numbers, taken from DataView. I'm iterating through the DataView and add the series.  
By default, the axes labels will be 1...x. 
If you define: `chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "ddd";`, then the labels will be days of week, but **always** start from Sunday, no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you set a `LabelStyle.Interval` the `Labels` try to follow the `DataPoints`, restrained by the available space. When the are enough they will default to *Sunday*.

You can change this to start at a fixed other day be setting the `LabelStyle.IntervalOffset`; to always start on a *Monday* add `1`:

```
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;

ax.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = 1;
```

to make them always start on the current day of the week use this:

```
ax.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Combined with this

```
ax.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
ax.LabelStyle.Interval = 7;
```

only `Labels` with a fixed weekday will display.

Comment: Tip: If you are using an interval of weeks instead of days, then you must set `LabelStyle.IntervalOffsetType` to `DateTimeIntervalType.Days`. Otherwise, you need to specify the IntervalOffset in weeks instead of days (0.125 to offset by one day)